# Agregar filas de acuerdo a una consulta en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Buen día con todos, tengo una consulta en MySQL que me esta matando, espero puedan ayudarme.
Lo que estoy buscando es que cuando en los contadores tenga mas de 1 archivo(registro) se debe realizar una fila en el resultado del query, esto con la finalidad de llamar a un campo de la tabla archivos

```
   select producto,lote,categoria,marca,usuario,
    (select count(*) from archivos where producto_id=p.id and lote_id=l.id) cant_total,registrosanitario,nombreproductors,
    (select count(*) from archivos where producto_id=p.id and lote_id=l.id and tipo='registrosanitario') registrosanitario,
    (select count(*) from archivos where producto_id=p.id and lote_id=l.id and tipo='protocolo') protocolo,
    (select count(*) from archivos where producto_id=p.id and lote_id=l.id and tipo='fichatecnica') fichatecnica,fabricante,
    (select count(*) from archivos where producto_id=p.id and lote_id=l.id and tipo='bpm') bpm
     from productos p 
inner join lotes l on p.id=l.producto_id 
inner join categorias c on p.categoria_id=c.id
inner join marcas m on p.marca_id=m.id
inner join usuarios u on p.usuario_id=u.id
left join fabricantes f on p.fabricante_id=f.id
left join registros_sanitarios r on p.registrosanitario_id=r.id
order by producto,lote
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No se si me deje entender, lo que debería salir es 7 filas, ya que la columna protocolo tiene 2 registros.

Este es mi tabla: archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**#Update:**

Los count(*) se reemplazaran con el campo fechavencimiento de la tabla Archivos(imagen2); lo que estoy buscando es un agrupamiento que cruce entre las tablas Productos, Lotes y Archivos, en donde Archivos tiene los fk de las otras tablas; pero con la diferenciación del campo tipo de la tabla Archivos. Por ejemplo, referente a la imagen 2, hay 2 registros que tienen el mismo producto_id, lote_id y tipo, entonces esos datos deben figurar 2 veces en la imagen 1, para mostrar la fechavencimiento de cada uno.

***Adjunto Fiddle para una mejor referencia.***

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9R162JRuVFUq36hLpytL6E/6

Lo que espero:

```
|producto             | lote    | categoria       | marca    | usuario       | cant_total | rs  | nombrep | rs | p | ft | fabric | bpm |
|Campo Dental         | 20201205 | Material Dental | DISMED   | Administrador | 2          | Demo | dent   | 1  | 0 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
|Campo Dental         | 20211306 | Material Dental | DISMED   | Administrador | 0          | Demo | dent   | 0  | 0 | 0  | Prueba | 0  |
|Canulo de alto flujo | 1        | Material Médico | ASCMEDIC | Administrador | 4          | Demo | canulo | 1  | 2 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
|Canulo de alto flujo | 1        | Material Médico | ASCMEDIC | Administrador | 4          | Demo | canulo | 1  | 2 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
|Canulo de alto flujo | 2        | Material Médico | ASCMEDIC | Administrador | 2          | Demo | canulo | 1  | 0 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
|Canulo de alto flujo | 3        | Material Médico | ASCMEDIC | Administrador | 2          | Demo | canulo | 1  | 0 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
|Mandil SMS 40g.      | 1        | Material Médico | ASCMEDIC | Administrador | 3          | Demo | mandil | 1  | 1 | 0  | Prueba | 1  |
```

**#Update2:**
Viendolo desde otra perspectiva:

```
    select producto,lote,tipo,fechavencimiento from archivos a
inner join productos p on a.producto_id=p.id 
inner join lotes l on a.lote_id=l.id
order by a.producto_id,lote_id,tipo
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta consulta me lista todos los archivos que tengo, lo que quiero es que la columna "tipo" pase como fila o encabezado agrupando los productos y lotes, pero en el caso de que el tipo se repita (de 2 a más), salga la cantidad de veces ya sea como columna o fila

Comment: Hola. Pon la consulta SQL como texto, no como imagen. El código en imagen es difícil de analizar y no se puede reproducir. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Hola que tal, gracias por responder, acabo de actualizarlo.

Comment: Ahora se ve mejor, aunque el núcleo de la pregunta no logro entenderlo: *cuando en los contadores tenga mas de 1 archivo(registro) **se debe realizar una fila en el resultado del query ¿?***. ¿Qué quieres decir con esto exactamente? ¿Por qué tantos count(*) a la misma tabla en tu consulta? Por favor, sé más claro explicando el contexto y el problema.

Comment: Los count(*) se reemplazaran con el campo fechavencimiento de la tabla Archivos(imagen2); lo que estoy buscando es un agrupamiento que cruce entre las tablas Productos, Lotes y Archivos, en donde Archivos tiene los fk de las otras tablas; pero con la diferenciación del campo tipo de la tabla Archivos.
Por ejemplo, referente a la imagen 2, hay 2 registros que tienen el mismo producto_id, lote_id y tipo, entonces esos datos deben figurar 2 veces en la imagen 1, para mostrar la fechavencimiento de cada uno.

Comment: Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y aclara el problema redactando la pregunta. Quizá sea bueno que muestres un pequeño set de datos, incluso en un fiddle si es posible, para poder hacer pruebas. No logro entender del todo el problema, pero quizá lo que necesites sea algo del tip `SELECT ... CASE ... WHEN` y quizá ir acumulando en cada caso ¿?

Comment: ok... pero si el count es >= 2 entonces se duplica el registro con los mismos datos? o qué se hace? y veo que en algunos casos el count es igual a 0, por tanto ese registro no debería aparecer? mejor coloca la respuesta esperada.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: @lsanchezo asi es, si es mayor que 1 el registro deberia aparecer la cantidad de veces, si es 0 igual deberia aparecer. Lo que deberia salir es 7 filas (con referencia a la imagen1), ya que la columna protocolo tiene 2 registros.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta un ejemplo, en forma de texto, de los resultados que esperas? Sospecho que es más simple de obtener de lo que crees, pero al escribir un código tan enrevesado la solución se oscurece. En el planteamiento aún no queda claro qué es lo que debe hacer la consulta en base a los datos existentes.

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de actualizar la pregunta, ojala esta vez se entienda, yo tambien siento que es algo sencillo pero me estoy complicando, help mee!!

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, lo hice a través de php, tuve que hacer un bucle para mostrar la cantidad de tipos que contiene mis archivos.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).